# what does this line of code in the for statement mean or do?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, for-loop, tuples

am studying with a tutorial for a game app and there is a line of code that i didn't understood it looks like it's of type tuple

**this is my code:**

> ```
>  var algorithmResult = algorithm(value: value)
> ```

```
      func rowCheck(#value: Int) -> (location: String, pattern: String)? {
        var acceptableFinds = ["011", "101", "110"]
        var findFunc = [checkTop, checkBottom, checkMiddleAcross, checkRight, checkMiddleDown, checkLeft, checkDiagLeftRight, checkDiagRightLeft]
        for algorithm in findFunc {
 var algorithmResult = algorithm(value: value)

            if (find(acceptableFinds, algorithmResult.pattern) != nil) {
                return algorithmResult
            }
        }
        return nil
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In:

```
 var algorithmResult = algorithm(value: value)
```

`algorithm` represents one element in the `findFunc` array (as defined in `for algorithm in findFunc`).

From the names, I'm guessing each of those elements is a function. Those functions are passed `value` and the result of the function is stored in `algorithmResult`.

Here's a similar example. Create two functions:

```
func add(operand : Int) -> Int {
    return operand + operand
}

func multiply(operand : Int) -> Int {
    return operand * operand
}
```

Store them in an array:

```
let funcs = [add, multiply]
```

Call them in a loop:

```
for function in funcs {
    let x = function(5)
    print(x)
}
```

This prints:

```
10
25
```

Answer (score 0):

It applies each function from `findFunc` array to the value, which was passed to `rowCheck` function.